# Don't be afraid of the Close button

Tags: discussion

I've noticed lately that it seems not many people are using the close button.  I realize that we are in the middle of figuring out what is and isn't on topic for the site, but if you see something that seems like it is clearly off topic, particularly as discussed here, don't forget that using the close button will help keep the site clear of off-topic content.

If you see a question that has close votes and you aren't sure if it is actually off topic, feel free to bring up the question on Meta to discuss why it is or isn't off topic.

Comment: We should come up with a user script that plays sound effects for closing and flagging (not like we don't have the talent for said effects here)

Comment: I think there are a few people that like to use that close button every now and then, but don't have the required reputation to do so. Since Sound Design is a small community, the reputation of even active members is generally lower than in bigger stack exchange sections where a good question or answer quickly gets upwards of 20 upvotes.

Comment: @Emv - yeah, I just noticed today that the level is wrong for a beta site.  It's supposed to be 500 rep but somehow it is currently set at 3000.  I asked Tim if he could look in to getting that fixed.

Comment: That's a good idea. and whilst on the topic of moderating. is it possible to make it easier to close your own questions? there are a lot of questions that have been answered but are still open because you need x other persons to agree to close it.

Comment: an example: i can't close this question, because there are no answers. http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/17331/article-the-hum-that-helps-to-fight-crime

Comment: @ArnoudTraa - there seems to be a little confusion about how SE works here.  There are three possible things that can be done with a question to make it "done", a question can have an accepted answer, which doesn't actually close the question, but marks it as being answered so that people who are trying to find questions needing answers are less likely to look at it, however new answers can still be posted to it.  There is closed, which is used when a question isn't a good fit for the site and disables answering.  And finally, there is deletion, which removes the content from being visible..

Comment: to all but high reputation users and moderators.  There should never be a reason to close your own question.  You can either accept an answer or decide to delete it.  There is no point in closing an unanswered question of your own as a) it would be automatically deleted after a time anyway and b) it would become impossible for anyone to answer if it was closed.  There is one other rare condition, locked, locked posts can't be edited or updated, so it is kind of like a close on steroids, but that's a diamond mod only ability and only used when there are major problems based around a question.

Comment: ah yes i understand now, thanks for the info! i've 'marked' all my question's as answerred. indeed closing was not what i wanted.